# Getting GDB 8.0.1 to work in CLion on OSX High Sierra 10.13.4

Tags: c++, macos, gdb, code-signing, clion

Long story short - LLDB doesn't debug my program properly, so I need to use GDB on my Mac to debug a c++ project. Steps I've taken:

- Install GDB 8.0.1 and 8.1 via brew/macports (ie try all options)
- Codesign the binary properly.
- Start the mac in restart mode and typing csrutil enable --without debug
- Choose the custom GDB executable in Clion.
- Write in the .gdbinit file located in the home directory set startup-with-shell off

When I go to debug in Clion, in the debugger window it reads:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
[New Thread 0x2203 of process 1208]
warning: unhandled dyld version (15)
```

In the console window it just prints the path of the executable and then hangs there until eventually it says 'command timed out'.

Any ideas would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46844023/72178.

Comment: Perhaps similar. but no.

Comment: Have you tried using GDB 8.0.1 bundled with the latest CLion 2018.2 EAP? It has a fix for the `warning: unhandled dyld version (15)` which may help in your case.