# Unhandled dyId versions 15 when running gdb on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, gdb

When I tried to debug c file using gdb on my Mac.

I downloaded it by brew.(gdb ver 8.0.1) and also proceeded code singing.

But, still I have an error like this:

[image]

I can get the desired answer. But I want to fix this problem for long term use of gdb.

Comment: Please paste your session into the body of your question instead of including only a screenshot. This makes it easier for screen readers, search engines and potential answerers to understand your post. Thank you! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: This looks like it has not anything to do with gdb itself. Are you sure this warning is not coming from the debugged program (a.out) ? Please try debugging another binary!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`gdb\` unable to unwind a stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46844023/gdb-unable-to-unwind-a-stack)